# Change view on button click

Tags: iphone, uiview

I am doing an iPhone project.
As part of it I want to know how to load a uiview to half portion of the screen when we click on a button.

Comment: You can use addSubView method and set the frame to load only for half screen using CGRectMake method, on the click of a button

Comment: like facebook app?
verticle half of horizontal half?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UIView *customView =[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10,100,200,200);//Give frame according to your view 
customView.backgroundColor=[UIColor greenColor];
[Self.view addSubView: customView];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [addSubview](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/addSubview%3a): from [UIView Class](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html)